# Using a .R file as a resource and create a batch directly in C#

Tags: c#, r, winforms, batch-file, integration

I have a number of shiny applications with the file structure global.R, ui.R, server.R and something I call batchTrigger.R. The contents of the latter is simply the following-

```
.libPath(*Path to my R Package Repository*)
require('shiny')
runApp(*Path to the folder with the aforementioned files*)
```

I created a batch file called application.cmd with the following code-

```
cls
@pushd ""
:::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
ECHO Loading...Please, wait. The Application will open automatically. 
ECHO --- 
ECHO Do not close this console window for the whole duration of your session 
ECHO in the application.
ECHO ---
@echo off

"C:\Program Files\R\bin\Rscript.exe" ".../**batchTrigger.R**"

:::::::::::::::::::
@popd
cmd /k
```

This batch file is working just fine. Then I went one step further, and decided to create a windows form with multiple R Applications. I have two buttons in the form, each of which goes something like this-

```
 private void application1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "...\\**application1.cmd**";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K";
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.Start();
    }
```

So far, so good. Both the buttons work exactly as they were supposed to. I want to go one more step ahead, but since I am very new at C#, I need help. What I am hoping to get is a dynamic location for the R files and the cmd files within the thus deployed application, within the solution. In other words, I should be able to write the contents of the batch file *within* the C# code, and the path of the batchTrigger.R should be something which changes with the location of the windows form application (which will be a self contained deployed executable file). The idea is that the R package repository and R installation may remain static and can be pointed at by the batchTrigger.R and application.cmd respectively, but the location of batchTrigger.R itself along with other R files move with the application. I think that resource.resx can do something about this, but how exactly can I go about doing it, I don't seem to get. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered passing the parts of the bat file you want to be dynamic in as arguments to the bat script?  That might be simpler.

Comment: I am just realizing an error I made in my thoughts. The location of the global.R, ui.R and server.R files are pointed at by the batchTrigger.R file, which in itself is not a native format. That being said, @Dweeberly, I like your suggestion. I can make arguments in R script which I can source from outside, and if somehow C# can throw me the current location of the application as, say, a csv, I can perhaps read that as the main directory for my R scripts into the batchTrigger.R file. Do you think that would be a good way to do it?

Comment: I can't say there is a "right" path, but having your C# call a script with arguments gives additional flexibility in that you may find a time in the future where it is easier to modify your script file than recompile your C#.  [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) should get you the directory you are working in.

Comment: Really curious why you don't just start Rscript from c#. Writing a batchfile that starts rscript and starting the batch file from c# is adding an unnecessary middleman

Answer (score 0):

Make a general method:

```
private void StartSilentR(string rScriptFilePath)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\R\bin\Rscript.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = rScriptFilePath;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    //avoid this unless you must control the app via stdin
    //cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.Start();
}
```

Then write something that calls it after working out where the script is. For example if you have your directory structure as:

```
RLauncherCSharpApp.exe 
rscripts\ui.R
rscripts\global.R
rscripts\batchTrigger.R
```

Then in c# you can:

```
//take exe Path, remove exe name and add rscripts folder and batchtrigger.R file name 
var rbt = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "rscripts", "batchTrigger.R");

StartSilentR(rbt);
```

Or, say you want to search all the subfolders of the app's folder looking for all files called batchTrigger.R:

```
var exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(exeFolder, "batchTrigger.R", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//maybe add them to a list view and the user can click one to launch ..
```